# How to create and share static components with React?

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs

I would like to create a single component and include it across different components. Once the static component gets updated it should update across all components it is included in. How do I accomplish this?

```
var ActiveTag = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() { return {tag: ''}, 
  render() { return <span>{this.state.tag}</span> }} 
});

var PanelTitle = React.createClass({ render() { return <ActiveTag/> } })
var DocumentTitle = React.createClass({ render() { return <ActiveTag/> } })

ActiveTag.setState({tag: 'shared tag'}) // Both PanelTitle and DocumentTitle should update
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @erichardson30 Please see the edit.

Comment: Did that answer answer your question?

Comment: @erichardson30 That answer is definitely an option but I was wondering if there was a way doing it without utilizing the observer pattern. Also I want ActiveTag to point to the same instance for performance reasons.

Comment: You're going to want to pass it in as a prop to each component. So when the state updates, it will also re-render the other components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, the following line won't work:

```
ActiveTag.setState({tag: 'shared tag'}) // Both PanelTitle and DocumentTitle should update
```

You cannot/ should not access state from outside the component. The whole idea behind state is that it is internal to the component. You should really only use `setState()` from within the component itself.

If I understand correctly:

- you have a standard component
- with non-static info (because the component can apparently be updated)
- which is used in different places in your component tree

So your component needs to have some `props` or `state` (otherwise there is no update).

You can implement this in 2 ways:

**1. Using props:**
Define/ store the custom-component's props at the highest level in your component tree (probably react root component), and pass those props to ALL children in your component tree.
That way, everytime the prop updates, react will (efficiently) re-render the entire tree, and simultaniously update all instances of your custom-component.

An example using props would be (in pseudo code):

```
var ActiveTag = React.createClass({
  render() { return <span>{this.props.tag}</span> } 
});

var PanelTitle = React.createClass({ 
  render() { return <ActiveTag tag={this.props.tag}/> }
})
var DocumentTitle = React.createClass({ 
  render() { return <ActiveTag tag={this.props.tag}/> }
})

var ReactRoot = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {return { globalTag : 'initial value' }},
  componentDidMount() { this.setState({ globalTag: 'new value' }) },
  render() {
    return (
      <PanelTitle tag={this.state.globalTag} />
      <DocumentTitle tag={this.state.globalTag} />
  }
})
```

**2. Using state:**
Store the custom-components updateable stuff somewhere else (maybe in a flux store).
Implement state in your custom-component, and add an event-listener to changes to the store.
That way, everytime the updateable stuff in the store (or wherever) changes, the listener in each of your custom-components fires, updates state, and re-renders the custom-component.

Which of these is the best depends very much on context, structure and other factors of your component tree, the frequency of updates, complexity etc etc.

Comment: @erichardson30 Please see the edited question with an example.

Comment: Updated answer with an example of option 1.